# Парсинг повторяющейся строки

Tags: php

Есть строка вида - "0012345600123456", "123456123456". Может быть еще какие-то вариации, не суть важно. Число символов в строках разное, но суть в том, что все они "задвоенные".

Как можно разобрать эту строку и вытащить из нее "не задвоенное" значение (00123456, 123456)?

Comment: хз, можно попробовать разделить строку на 2, потом итерироваться по строке до получившийся длины и создавать новую строку

Comment: скопировать половину длины строки? `еще какие-то вариации` могут помешать, конечно

Comment: Нужно разбивать строку на массив цифр и записывать одинаковые последовательности, брать максимально длинную последовательность и по ней уже разбивать

Comment: @MBo, Я думал насчет этого, но также думал, что есть какой-то другой вариант

Comment: @InDevX, Понял, спасибо

Comment: @DimaRRR Если формат именно такой, то ничего проще быть не может

Comment: можно число с большей длинной взрывать во меньшему) ```explode('123456', '00123456')```

Comment: А если так: `^(\d+)\1$` конечно, как и во всех других вариантах, как быть с числами типа 11 или 222222 - это одно число или задвоенное

Comment: А что если - взять строку, а далее в цикле выполнять поиск по первому символу, первым двум, трем и тд пока не останется 2 результата, а далее просто разбить строку?

Comment: @DimaRRR Не понимаю, зачем что-то искать, если формат известен. А если неизвестен - то это совсем другая задача

Comment: @MBo, Дело в том, что это может быть задвоенная строка, может быть не задвоенная. Если задвоенная - там может быть как 5, так и 10 символов. Также она может выглядеть так - 00-012345600-0123456. Поэтому мне кажется, что тот вариант, который я написал - самый логичный

Comment: Значит, нужно описать задачу полноценно.

Answer (score 0):

1. Берем строку и разбиваем на массив.
2. Циклом начинаем поиск по исходной строке: по первому символу, по первым двум символам, по первым трем символам. И так до тех пор, пока не останется 2 результата.
3. Обрезаем строку с 0 до второго найденного фрагмента.